# grep workaround with pattern files on MacOS 10.13

Tags: grep, macos-high-sierra

I am having a perplexing problem with grep that I can't debug. This is reproducible on Mac OS High Sierra, but the problem does not occur on a current Ubuntu (where it works as expected).

I have three files:

```
cat haystack 
apple
aardvark
cow

cat pattern1
a
aardvark
animal

cat pattern2
c
b
apple
```

You can create these 3 files with:

```
perl -e 'print "a\naardvark\nanimal"' > pattern1;
perl -e 'print "c\nb\napple"' > pattern2;
perl -e 'print "apple\naardvark\ncow"' > haystack;
```

Here's the problem: This yields the expected response:

```
grep -iowFf pattern2 haystack
apple
```

To explain, the grep...

```
-i = case insensitive
-o = display the match
-w = word match <== this is the option which is breaking it
     The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]' and `[[:>:]]'
-F = fast grep (fixed strings)
-f = read pattern from file
```

This returns nothing:

```
grep -iowFf pattern1 haystack
```

But I would expect "`pattern1`" to return "`aardvark`".

I was experimenting with this small testbed, but my real project is much larger. And I found that when I change the sequence of the lines in the `patternN` files, the results change.

```
sort -r pattern1 > pattern1.reverse
grep -iowFf pattern1.reverse haystack
```

That returns "`aardvark`"

What am I missing? I've been banging my head on this. Is it a bug in MacOS 10.13? Is there a workaround?   (yes, one workaround is to replace the -w parameter with \b....\b in my patterns and turn off -F, but I am working on very large files, and I want the performance.)

Answer (score 4):

On MacOSX:

```
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

On Centos7 e.g.

```
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

Now, both versions work differently (as you noticed). To workaround this you can install the GNU version of grep on MacOSX with `brew install grep` which installs GNU grep with the prefix `g`. Now you can do:

```
$ ggrep -iowFf pattern1 haystack
aardvark
```